# Merge the "osx-mavericks" and "mavericks" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A merge/synonym request:

- [mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mavericks) — 1020 tagged, 62 this week, 10 today

  > OS X 10.9, Mavericks, is the tenth iteration of the computer operating system, OS X.
- [osx-mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx-mavericks) — 10 tagged, 10 this month, 9 this week

  > Version 10.9.x of the Mac Operating System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That follows what we've done for other OS names.

```
Tag Synonym osx-mavericks -> mavericks was approved!
```